# Monte Carlo Multiple Distributions

Tags: java, probability, distribution, montecarlo

I have been struggling with an issue relating to the summation of multiple Risks' triangular distributions using Monte Carlo. I can get the correct shape of generation but the percentage probability is far off. This is what I am generating for 2 risks with values for probability, best case, most likely and worst case (75%, 100-200-300)(80%, 510-1000-1125):
[image: My attempt]

And this is the tool I am basing my accuracy on:

[image: Their attempt]

This is a recurring issue and I can't seem to find a solution. When I calculate a single risk using the same formula, the result is 99% accurate to the comparison tool. This is my distribution addition formula:

```
public static List<Double> combineLists(Double weight, List<Double> newDataList, List<Double> cumulativeDataList){
    //loops through the size of the new data list to added
    for(Integer i = 0; i < newDataList.size(); i++){
        //sets the output as the sum of both
        cumulativeDataList.set(i, cumulativeDataList.get(i) + (newDataList.get(i)*weight));
    }
    return cumulativeDataList;
```

Further to this, I cannot find the way of how they generate their max/worst values, I am simply summing the worst from all risks(1425) but they have a value of 1388, any suggestions on this would also be appreciated.

I have been stuck on this for weeks so any help would be very appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: the input data and all has to be the same - as far as the simple addition formula I dont see anything peculiar- we dont know all the rest: what is this "comparison tool" and how it operates the data, what is the rest of your program?

Comment: The input data is identical and I have checked this tool (IntoRisk) against other industry Monte Carlo programs which give very similar results. I was asking if anyone knew the particular reason as to how to alter the probability and what would affect it to equalize my implementation to theirs. I can give you snippets of other sections of my program if you like?

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't fully understand. (1) What does the "75%" in (75%, 100-200-300) mean? (2) What do you mean by "add"? Do you mean "add" in the sense of: sample x1 from risk distribution1, sample x2 from risk distribution2, return x1 + x2 ?? The curves you show don't appear to be cumulative probabilities from such a sum, since they both have a flat spot for some distance in the middle -- this indicates that the density must be zero there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! The 75% is the probability of the risk occurring, I am currently applying this as the weight in the code snippet above. I am also applying a combined percentage at the end of all calculations to get the start point of the line (starts at 5% instead of 0). I am looking for a way to combine multiple distributions, I have implemented the code snippet for this, I have tried simply adding x1 + x2 but this also does not give the correct results. The two densities are separated as they have no overlapping bounds, the density is 0 in the middle for this reason.

Comment: @JoshWindsor If the % represents the probability that the risk occurs, don't they have to add up to 100%? What does it mean if one is 75% and the other is 80% A larger question is what you mean by combining the two risks. Do these represent risks of two separate tasks or actions, or competing risks (i.e. you get one or the other) for the same action, or what? Thanks for the clarification, I appreciate it.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you for the reply, I have thought about this and have tried summing the percentages and dividing to get a weighted percent out of 1, but this also does not alter results. I am currently attempting to do an independant forecast, ie - each risk is separate and has no cause association between them. Although if 100% cause association is more applicable then I would happily accept any help/solutions on that. Thanks again

Comment: @JoshWindsor Here is the kind of consideration I have in mind. If you have two tasks and you must do both, then the total risk is the sum of the two separate risks (assuming that risk = expected cost or something like that). The probability density of the sum of two variables is the convolution of the two separate densities -- that will make one bump out of two. If, by chance, you only do one task (e.g. if it snows, you do task 1 else task 2) then the total risks is alpha times p(risk 1) plus (1 - alpha) times p(risk 2) where alpha is the probability of the event that requires you to do task1.

Comment: @JoshWindsor alpha times p(risk 1) plus (1 - alpha) times p(risk 2) is a so-called mixture distribution and it has two bumps if p(risk 1) and p(risk 2) are separated enough. So as you can see, how to combine risk 1 and risk 2 depends on the problem you are trying to solve. There are probably other ways to combine them -- what method comes into play depends strongly on your problem.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the solution but this has given me a very similar result to the previous although the plateau is at 80%(similar result to other attempts I have made). This leads me to believe that my problem lies somewhere else. Could my problem potentially be in the flow of my program, I have compiled my steps into a list here: http://pastebin.com/qi30u1Tz Could potentially be in the way I calculate an overall bin list? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @RobertDodier To clarify, I used your solution: alpha times p(risk 1) plus (1 - alpha) times p(risk 2), before and after my normal calculation both giving the same results. I could also compile an album of comparisons between different distributions of both my normal and cumulative if required.

Comment: @JoshWindsor I looked at the list of steps, and to be honest it seems like it could be simplified a lot. If, in fact, all you need to do is construct the mixture density, then you can omit the normal approximation (this is possibly the origin of the discrepancy with the result you are using for comparison) and also the Monte Carlo stuff. But whether the mixture density is the right thing depends on the larger context of the problem, as I was saying before. Incidentally if you need to sample from a mixture density: pick k according to the alpha's; then sample from the k'th density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer, it was that the probability needed to be integrated within the random number generator! This removed the need for half of the steps as the data was already normally distributed.